# DSAS tool compatibility with ArcMap 10.4?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, file-geodatabase, arcgis-10.4, arctoolbox, digital-shoreline-analysis-system

Using ArcGIS Desktop 10.4 I am attempting to quantify rate of shoreline change using the USGS's DSAS tool for arcmap. I am able to complete every step up until I run the statistics in which I get the error message:

`C:\Users\mfazio\AppData\Roaming\USGS\DSAS\calc\DSASCore.calc.exe  -e -d "C:\Users\mfazio\AppData\Roaming\USGS\DSAS\data\20170912_101754.Tansect_S100.in.xml" -o "C:\Users\mfazio\AppData\Roaming\USGS\DSAS\data\20170912_101754.Tansect_S100.DSASCore.out.xml" -c "SCE,NSM,EPR,LRR,WLR,LMS"
[9/12/2017 10:18:40 AM] : ********EXCEPTION INFO BEGIN*********
[9/12/2017 10:18:40 AM] : System Exception:
[9/12/2017 10:18:40 AM] : Exception Source:
[9/12/2017 10:18:40 AM] : ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase
[9/12/2017 10:18:40 AM] : Exception Target Site:
[9/12/2017 10:18:40 AM] : ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.ICursor Search(ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IQueryFilter, Boolean)
[9/12/2017 10:18:40 AM] : Exception Message:
[9/12/2017 10:18:40 AM] : The server threw an exception. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010105 (RPC_E_SERVERFAULT))
[9/12/2017 10:18:40 AM] : System Exception:
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80010105): The server threw an exception. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010105 (RPC_E_SERVERFAULT))
   at ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.ITable.Search(IQueryFilter QueryFilter, Boolean Recycling)
   at DSAS.RateCalculation.readStatsFromFile(String outputTableName, String filename)`

I'm wondering if this is an issue multiple people are having or just me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has been resolved. It turns out they released a new version of the plug-in (DSAS v4.4) and can be found [here](https://woodshole.er.usgs.gov/project-pages/DSAS/version4/index.html).